# BluetoothHealth Profile in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Android 4.0 specs out Bluetooth Health devices and indicates that the api allows communication with devices that implement the Bluetooth Health Profile.  However there are multiple BLE Health relates profiles such as heart rate monitor profile and thermometer profile, but now Health Profile.  What Profile does BluetoothHealth actually support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.0 supports the Health Device Profile (HDP).  This is a traditional Bluetooth profile, not to be confused with similar Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) profiles such as Health Thermometer and Hear Rate Monitor.